# putExtra getExtra in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass some information from one activity to another with the help of putExtra and GetExtra but the activity crashes by showing the runtime exception.Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you are using and the exception and stack trace from the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Your extra object is basic type, serializable, Parcelable?